# Parse C# list as raw text in Razor view

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I'm trying to render a list of data in a Razor view in .net core.
I have a controller with the following

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        List<Video> videos = await _context.Video.ToListAsync();

        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(videos);
        return View(videos);
    }
```

and in my view i try to get the list of views with

```
<div data-videos="@Html.Raw(@Model)">
```

Obviously i can get the data in a loop like this `@foreach (var item in Model)` but i need it as plain text/json on the data attribute.
How can i achieve that?

Comment: SerializeObject returns a string. You should pass that to the view, rather than the videos object instance

Answer (score 1):

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(videos);
```

Does not do an inline replace on the value of videos.  You're basically Serializing `videos` and not storing the value.

It's important to note that the following signature for:

```
return View(string);
```

[will return a view with the name of the string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.view?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Controller_View_System_String_), it **does not pass the string as a model**.

So to force it you have to do something like:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(videos);
return View(json as Object);
```

then you should be able to:

```
@model string
<div data-videos="@Html.Raw(@Model)">
```

Comment: `return View(json as Object);` ugh, what an ugly hack. I'd rather `return View(nameof(ActionName), json);`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, Honestly the signature should have been `View(object Model, string ViewName)`... then it's never an issue.  Fairly large oversight...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you found out when you got the "View cannot be found" error, as everyone I know :)

Comment: Yeah Rather have the Compile time Error then that Run-Time error that ISN'T helpful.